# How to analyze density of states?

Tags: density-of-states, hydrogen-bonds

I have plotted the density of states (DOS) for my System with Hydrogen-rich and hydrogen lean [image: See Figure]. When the system is Hydrogen lean, the valence band maximum (HOMO) shifted towards Fermi level and bandgap of the system decreased.
How I can explain this DOS in terms of pi, pi*, sigma, sp3, sp2, localization, and delocalization of charge?

Answer (score 9):

As noted by @Camps, you can gain a lot of information from a projected density of states by looking at the contribution of a given orbital. However, it won't directly tell you a  lot of information about "bonding character," as you mention in your follow-up comment.

If you are specifically interested in "bonding character" when using a plane-wave DFT code, you're going to need to carry out a population analysis dedicated to such a task. Arguably, your best bet would be to carry out a Crystal Orbital Hamilton Population (COHP) analysis using [LOBSTER](http://www.cohp.de/). Another option that can provide similar orbital-based information is a periodic Natural Bonding Orbital (NBO) analysis, as implemented in [this code](https://github.com/jrschmidt2/periodic-NBO). There is also the Solid State Adaptive Natural Density Partitioning (SSAdNDP) method, as implemented [here](http://ion.chem.usu.edu/%7Eboldyrev/ssadndp.php).

Comment: You got my point. I have LOBSTER data (ICOOP, ICOHP, Mullikan's Population analysis, etc) but I do not understand how to correlate there analysis with density of states.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do that, you need to use the Partial Density of States (PDOS) were you can have the contribution of each atom/orbital to the DOS.

Comment: Yes, I have that. From DFT point of view, we can say about orbital contribution. But I need to understand in terms of bonding character.